# Hardhat compile, deploy and verify in a single script

Tags: automation, scripting, blockchain, ethereum, hardhat

I am using hardhat to compile, deploy and verify an Ethereum Smart Contract. Currently, I am mannually peforming these commands:

1. `npx hardhat compile`
2. `npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js`

Wait until the deployment script returns the contract address. Then manually copy the returned address to the verify command:

3. `npx hardhat verify 0x<contract-address>`
4. Copy the compiled contract json (abi) file to my project's directory in the filesystem.

Is there any way that I can run all these commands automatically? I am thinking to automate it using shell/bash/powershell scripting but I am not sure if this is the best way to achieve this.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just saw this so just posting my answer for future reference.

1. Running `npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js` automatically compiles uncompiled code. So you don't need to run it every time.
2. For the **Automation** you mentioned (**deploy + verify in one script**) you can just add the below lines of code in your `deploy.js` script to automatically verify it after it deploys:

   ```
      //wait for 5 block transactions to ensure deployment before verifying

      await myContract.deployTransaction.wait(5);

      //verify

      await hre.run("verify:verify", {
        address: myContract.address,
        contract: "contracts/MyContract.sol:MyContract", //Filename.sol:ClassName
      constructorArguments: [arg1, arg2, arg3],
   });
   ```

Now you can just call your usual deploy command `npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js` and the terminal will log the deployment + the verification like:

```
MyContract deployed to "0xTheDeployedContractAddress"  constructor arguments:  arg1, arg2, arg3
Nothing to compile
Successfully submitted source code for contract
contracts/MyContract.sol:Contrac at 0xTheDeployedContractAddress
for verification on the block explorer. Waiting for verification result...

Successfully verified contract HoloVCore on Etherscan.
https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0xTheDeployedContractAddress#code
```

Here's a sample of my overall `deploy.js` script

```
    const hre = require("hardhat");

    async function main() {
       const arg1 = "Contract Name";
       const arg2 = "TKN";
       const arg3 = 100000;
       const MyContract = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("MyContract");
       const myContract = await MyContract.deploy(arg1, arg2, arg3);

       await myContract.deployed();

       console.log(`VLX Token deployed to ${myContract.address}`);

       //wait for 5 block transactions to ensure deployment before verifying
       await myContract.deployTransaction.wait(5);

       //verify (source: https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/plugins/nomiclabs-hardhat-etherscan#using-programmatically)
       await hre.run("verify:verify", {
          address: myContract.address,
          contract: "contracts/MyContract.sol:MyContract", //Filename.sol:ClassName
          constructorArguments: [arg1, arg2, arg3],
       });
    }

    main().catch((error) => {
       console.error(error);
       process.exitCode = 1;
    });
```

*Remember to adjust the wait(n) parameter to adjust the wait time depending on the traffic on the network you're deploying to.*

For more info about programatically verifying, check this link from [Hardhat-Etherscan docs](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/plugins/nomiclabs-hardhat-etherscan#using-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a folder called utils and import it into your deploy folder in a much more organized manner.

```
const { run } = require("hardhat")

const verify = async (contractAddress, args) => {
    console.log("Verifying contract...")
    try {
        await run("verify:verify", {
            address: contractAddress,
            constructorArguments: args,
        })
    } catch (e) {
        if (e.message.toLowerCase().includes("already verified")) {
            console.log("Already verified!")
        } else {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }
}

module.exports = {
    verify,
}
```